# Animate position step by step

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to animate a div position on its left property. This position has to move step by step during all duration.

Here's my sample code :

```
#my-div {
  position: relative;
  top: -1291px;
  left: 615px;
  animation: my-div-anim 20s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: step-start;
}

@keyframes my-div-anim {
  0% {left: 615px;}
  20% {left: 800px;}
  40% {left: 985px;}
  60% {left: 1170px;}
  100% {left: 1170px;}
}
```

But it doesn't work. What could be wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does work in Chrome (with browser prefixes). I'm just not sure it does what you intend...

**step-start**

> This keyword represents the timing function steps(1, start). Using
>   this timing function, **the animation jumps immediately to the end state**
>   and stay in that position until the end of the animation.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function#step-start)

This means that your animation jumps directly to the last frame and misses out all of the intermediary positions. Are you certain this is the effect you want?

[Here is a demo showing that your animation is working](http://jsfiddle.net/dUZSp/). See how the text changes colour immediately.

Change the timing function to `ease` and the position animation works. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dUZSp/1/)

Comment: Well, not really. The timing function is applied to every step. Since you have defined 5 keyframes, that means 4 steps. 1/5 of the time, left will be 615 px (the end of the first transition, i.e. the second keyframe. the second 1/5 of the time, will be 800px, and so on.

Comment: @vals Thats not how it appears to work in the fiddle

Comment: Thanks for your demo, I'll have a closer look on it